# using javascript to add html div with dynamic elements issues

Tags: javascript, html

The following script is called upon to dynamically add html input elements.
There are two issues with the marked code (about 30 lines in) below.

1) Two input boxed should be displayed, when I add the marked code below the second input box (foox1 - "last name") is not being displayed.

2) The second is that I need id='suggestions' to be dynamic i.e. linked to foox1.  I should be using setAttribute as I have with the rest of the code but I need to get 1) above working first.

```
<script language="javascript">

var x = 1;

function add() {
var fooId = "foo";

for (i=1; i<=2; i++)
  {
    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("input");

    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", fooId+x+i);
    element.setAttribute("name", fooId+x+i);
    element.setAttribute("id", fooId+x+i);

    if(i==1){
           element.setAttribute("value", "First name");
           element.setAttribute("onkeyup", "lookup(this.value);");
           element.setAttribute("onblur", "fill();");

     }
    if(i==2){
          element.setAttribute("value", "Last name");

    }
    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
    foo.appendChild(element);

    /************************************************
    This is where the problem is, in this if statement.  
    This part of the code is required for an autofil in the text box

    ************************************************/

    if(i==1){
        foo.appendChild("<div class='suggestionsBox' id='suggestions' style='display: 
            none;'><img src='upArrow.png' style='position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;'         
            alt='upArrow' /><div class='suggestionList' id='autoSuggestionsList'>&nbsp;       </div>    </div>");
    }

    /********************************
    end of code with issues
    ******************************/

    var space = document.createTextNode(" ");
    foo.appendChild(space);  

}
        i++;            
            var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.setAttribute("type", "button");
    element.setAttribute("value", "Remove");
    element.setAttribute("id", fooId+x+i);
    element.setAttribute("name", fooId+x+i);    
    element.setAttribute("onclick", "removeRow(this)");
    foo.appendChild(element);

    var br = document.createElement("br");
    foo.appendChild(br);

    x++;

}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: please add a jsfiddle example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `.appendChild` in the below context. `.appendChild` adds a node not a string.

```
foo.appendChild("<div class='suggestionsBox' id='suggestions' style='display: 
            none;'><img src='upArrow.png' style='position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;'         
            alt='upArrow' /><div class='suggestionList' id='autoSuggestionsList'>&nbsp;       </div>    </div>");
```

It has to be

```
foo.innerHTML += "<div class='suggestionsBox' id='suggestions' style='display: none;'><img src='upArrow.png' style='position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;' alt='upArrow' /><div class='suggestionList' id='autoSuggestionsList'>&nbsp;  </div>   </div>";
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/8Ay56/)

**EDIT:** For the second part of your question, you can do `id='suggestions_for_' + fooId + x + i` in the above mentioned statement. (It will produce something like `id='suggestions_for_foo11'`.)

Answer (score 0):

you need to end each of those first two lines with `" +`